# How “LIKE” by LONG VARCHAR?

Tags: vertica

I had DB Vertica 8.0. Create schema WAREHOUSE with table include field by type LONG VARCHAR. Now I tried to execude SELECT for example

```
SELECT * FROM WAREHOUSE.ALL_EVENTS a 
WHERE 
a.original_data like '%d963%'
```

returned error

```
SQL Error [4286] [42883]: [Vertica][VJDBC](4286) ERROR: Operator does not exist: long varchar ~~ unknown
  [Vertica][VJDBC](4286) ERROR: Operator does not exist: long varchar ~~ unknown
    com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4286) ERROR: Operator does not exist: long varchar ~~ unknown
```

In Oracle I used dbms_lob package for CLOB fields.

Vertica have simular package for LONG VARCHAR types?

How "LIKE" by LONG VARCHAR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the [fine manual](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Predicates/LIKE-predicate.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Language%2520Elements%7CPredicates%7C_____7) the (SQL standard) LIKE predicate in Vertica accept CHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY and VARBINARY data types.

To perform LIKE operations on LONG VARCHAR columns you can use `REGEXP_LIKE` (no need to install/use any special package). This way:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM WAREHOUSE.ALL_EVENTS a 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(a.original_data, 'd963');
```

That's all.